# How do I redirect output from a command line app (howie AIML interpreter) to another command line app (espeak)?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, text-to-speech, espeak

I'd like to interact with an AIML interpreter that runs on the command line (Howie) using standard input and have the output played using espeak.

I've tried:

> ./runme.py | espeak --stdin

No success yet.

Comment: The command posted will send the standard output from runme.py to the standard input of espeak.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing then that I have some other issue, perhaps with the Raspberry Pi I'm running this on, because I should be hearing audio, but I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I wanted:

```
echo "Welcome to the lab $(cat /var/mail/pi|grep "was granted entry" |grep -v "<p>" | sed "s/ was.*/ /"|tail -1 | awk -F ", " ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; }')" |espeak -ven-us+f4 -s150 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you can try to write the stdout to a file with tee and then use espeak -f  to have it spoken.

so, for example if my script script.sh returns something,

```
./script.sh | tee >> output ; espeak -f output && rm output
```

would  first write all the contents written to stdout. However, it would start speaking only after completion. The file written will be deleted later on too.